# 'npm run build' failed with Amazon Linux 2023 but succeeded locally

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, gitlab-ci

I have a Node js application deployed to AWS using gitlab-ci. However, in the Build stage the 'npm run build' always failed with error:

```
Step 8/16 : ADD . /app
 ---> 11d6baab2a3a
Step 9/16 : RUN npm run build
 ---> Running in b6900b471a04
> synapse-cicd-api-backend@0.0.1 prebuild
> rimraf dist
> synapse-cicd-api-backend@0.0.1 build
> nest build
npm ERR! path /app
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! signal SIGKILL
npm ERR! command sh -c -- nest build
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-04-04T08_32_15_000Z-debug-0.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build' returned a non-zero code: 1
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

Does anyone encounter this issue before? I really appreciate any help!

On my local PC, when I run 'npm run build', the build is successful.
So there is no error in the Docker file.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/docker/library/node:16-alpine
WORKDIR /app
ADD package.json /app/package.json
ADD package-lock.json /app/package-lock.json
RUN apk --no-cache add curl
RUN npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org
RUN npm ci
ADD . /app
RUN npm run build
RUN ls -l
WORKDIR /app/openapi2apigee
RUN npm ci
RUN ls -l
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```